# jsoup gives blank output

Tags: java, android

I would like to show the data from the div `spotlight`, from the following page,

```
www.theregister.co.uk/2014/12/19/arguments_abound_about_seriousness_of_linux_grinch_vulnerability/
```

and I am using AsyncTask class to load and show the data in the Webview but my output is nothing but a blank screen,

```
// URL Address
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.description);
                new GetDesc().execute();
    }
    // Description AsyncTask
    private class GetDesc extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Elements> {

        Elements description = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Description.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Elements doInBackground(Void... params) {


            String url = "www.theregister.co.uk/2014/12/19/arguments_abound_about_seriousness_of_linux_grinch_vulnerability/"

            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                description = document.select("id#spotlight");  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return description;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Elements result) {
            // Set description into TextView

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            String html = result.toString();
            String mime = "text/html";
            String encoding = "utf-8";

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);

        }
    }
```

I have tried other divs too but all i am getting is a blank screen and I have no idea it is not loading properly. What am I doing wrong ?

If i try to load meta data then the code works fine, 
for example,

```
description = document.select("meta[name=twitter:site");
                desc = description.attr("content");
```

and then display `desc` then it works,

```
String html = desc;
            String mime = "text/html";
            String encoding = "utf-8";

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
```

Why the meta displays but the divs data doesnt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is the attribute name. You need to use the value of the attribute rather than the attribute identifer itself. i.e.

```
description = document.select("div#spotlight");
```